# Limit of a mean sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, faq

The recursive formula is $$t_n=\frac {t_{n-1}+t_{n-2}}2$$ as $n$ approaches infinity the mean sequence converges at a certain number. Changing $t_1$ and $t_2$ changes the number where the sequence converges.

Find a relationship between $t_1, t_2$ and where the mean sequence converges.

Prove the relationship.

What i have so far

[Working part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcBN2.png)

[Continuation of working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoSA3.png)

then i will proceed to plug in an into the formula given by @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг [limtn=t1+∑∞n=2(tn−tn−1)] and solve. Where does that equation come from and how could i better format this

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: note:  I reformatted your post pretty heavily.  Please check that I didn't change your meaning.

Comment: No, you did not change the meaning. Thank you for making the post clear with your edit.

Comment: As a remark, notice that $t_n$ will just be $\tfrac{F_n}{2^n}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number (with $F_{0,1} = t_{0,1}$).

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud what does (with F0,1=t0,1) this mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $t_1 \leq t_2$ WLOG, it is easy to see that $t_1 \leq t_n \leq t_2$ for all $n$. Now, because $t_n$ is bounded, there exists a convergent subsequence of this sequence. Finally, note that $t_1 \leq t_2 \geq t_3 \leq t_4 \leq t_5 $ etc.

I claim further that $t_n$ is Cauchy.Note that $(t_n - t_{n-1}) = \dfrac{(t_{n-1} - t_{n-2})(-1)^{n}}{2}$, so it is a positive sequence that decreases to zero.

Finally,  every Cauchy sequence with a convergent sequence is itself a convergent sequence, hence $\lim t_n$ exists as $n \to \infty$.

Now, since the limit exists, it is correct to write: $\lim t_n = t_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (t_n - t_{n-1})$. But then, we observe that this is just $t_1 + (t_2-t_1) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big(\frac{-1}{2} \Big)^n = t_1+(t_2-t_1)\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3} t_1 + \frac{2}{3}t_2$.

Hence the limit is $\frac{t_1+2t_2}{3}$ when $t_1 \leq  t_2$. It would switch if the comparison also flips.

Comment: Great answer, cleared a lot of my doubts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you. This is the way you should approach this problem in the analysis course. If you are taught recurrence relations you should approach it in a different way, but this is the best for general understanding.

Comment: Yes, and I'm attending my first analysis course so this approach makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг how did you find that  limtn=t1+∑∞n=2(tn−tn−1)

Comment: @Jane expand it, it will expand like $t_1 + (t_2-t_1) + (t_3-t_2) + ...$, so can you see what will be left at the end?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг you get left with tn so its true by definition?

Comment: @Jane it's  true if the sequence is convergent, isn't it? Hence I am able to make the switch.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг yes, it is true. I just want to know how you found it or is it a well-known formula or something.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$2t_n -t_{n-1}-t_{n-2}=0$ therefore $t_n=Ax_1^n + Bx_2^n$ where $x_1, x_2$ are the solutions of $2x^2 -x -1 =0$ and $A, B$ are constants determined by the $t_1, t_2$ values.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial associated with the recurrence relation is
$$P(x) = x^2 - \frac12x -\frac12$$

The roots are $1$ and $-1/2$. Since they're all distinct, the $n$-th term of the relation can be written as
$$t_n = c_1 {\left(-\frac12\right)}^n + c_2.$$

The two constants are chosen in order to fit the first terms. In our case, we have:
$$\begin{cases}
t_1 = -\frac12 c_1 + c_2\\[1ex]
t_2 = \frac14 c_1 + c_2
\end{cases}$$
giving
$$\begin{cases}
c_1 = \frac43(t_2 - t_1)\\[1ex]
c_2 = \frac13(t_1 + 2t_2)
\end{cases}$$

It follows that
$$t_n = {(-1)}^n\frac{2^{2-n}}3(t_2 - t_1) + \frac13(t_1 + 2t_2)$$

Can you conclude?

Comment: Thank you for the response ill work on concluding it and post what I found later. Currently, I'm figuring out how to convert to the characteristic polynomial as I have never seen this before (senior year in high school). I'm working on it and look forward to sharing what i get. Thanks again. update its not that hard i figured the conversion out

Comment: @Jane Great! If you have further questions I'll be happy to help. Also, if you found the answer useful, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark below the vote buttons.