# Proving a general rule which states where a recursive series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, recursive-algorithms, faq

The recursive formula is

$t_n=\frac {t_{n-1}+t_{n-2}}2$

Changing $t_1$ and $t_2$ changes the number where the sequence converges as $n \to \infty$. With the help of everyone at StackExchange, I found that the relationship between $t_1$ and $t_2$ and where the series converges is

$\frac{t_1+2t_2}{3}$

However, how do I prove that that equation describes the relationship between $t_1$ and $t_2$ and where the series converges?

[The way I found the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcFbz.png)

sidenote: if someone could explain here the first equation in the picture I uploaded comes from it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about eigenvalues/eigenvectors?  Have you heard the phrase "dynamical system"?

Comment: It looks from the link that you have a copy of a printed text version of the solution, but in the link label you say "the way I found the formula". Which is it?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have not. I'm a senior in high school so I was hope for a fairly basic solution sorry.

Comment: @coffeemath that was how I derived the formula. I don't think it counts as a proof.

Comment: @Jane that's perfectly fine; that's exactly why I asked before I said anything else.

Comment: [Related: Jane's earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921376/limit-of-a-mean-sequence)

Comment: **Note:** we can write the recursion in the form
$$
2t_n -  t_{n-1} - t_{n-2} = 0
$$
notably, every sequence built via this recursion can be expressed as
$$
t_n = a_1 r_1^n + a_2 r_2^n
$$
where $a_1,a_2$ are some constants, and $r_1,r_2$ are solutions to the equation $2r^2 - r - 1 = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I saw this answer in my previous post I don't see how one goes from $2t_n -  t_{n-1} - t_{n-2} = 0$ to $t_n = a_1 r_1^n + a_2 r_2^n$ or why $r_1,r_2$ are the solutions to the equation $2r^2 - r - 1 = 0$ so i stayed away from it.

Comment: @Jane I see that in the original now.  Anyway, I'll just leave the comment as a point to be considered.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom do you know where this equation  $\lim t_n = t_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (t_n - t_{n-1})$ comes from? I have expanded and see that it is true however I want to have an idea of how one gets that formula because currently I just pull it out of thin air and use it to find the relationship between terms and where the sequence converges.

Comment: Jane-- I just put up an alternate way to see the limit is what you have, let me know if some steps need explaining.

Comment: Thanks for the different way. How do you find that $u_1=2(a-b)/3$ and $u_2=(b-a)/3$ from $u_n=t_n-(a+2b)/3$

Comment: @coffeemath Nevermind stupid question, I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a=t_1,\ b=t_2,$ then you're trying to show that $t_n$ approaches $(a+2b)/3$ as $n \to \infty.$ Note that the recursion $t_n=(t_{n-1}+t_{n-2})/2$ continues to hold when $t_n$ is replaced everywhere by $t_n-c$ where $c$ is any constant independent of $n.$ [One is subtracting $c$ from the left side and $(c/2+c/2)$ from the right side.] In this suppose we use $c=(a+2b)/3.$

So now we are looking at $u_n=t_n-(a+2b)/3$ and hoping that $u_n$ approaches zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Note that $u_1=2(a-b)/3$ and $u_2=(b-a)/3,$ so that we have the nice relation that $u_2=(-1/2)\cdot u_1.$ We can now show this continues to be so for higher index values $n.$ That is, we claim in general that
$$u_{n+1}=(-1/2)\cdot u_n \tag{1}$$
This is shown by "induction" meaning we show *if* it holds for a pair $n,n+1$ then it holds for the next pair $n+1,n+2.$ Now since it holds for the first pair, we have $u_{n+1}=(-1/2)\cdot u_n.$ To get $u_{n+2}$ we average $u_n$ and $u_{n+1}$:
$$u_{n+2}=\frac{u_n+u_{n+1}}{2}=\frac{u_n+(-1/2)u_n}{2} =\frac{u_n}{4}.$$
And now, since $u_{n+1}=(-1/2)\cdot u_n,$ we see that indeed $u_{n+2}=(-1/2)\cdot u_{n+1}$

A look at $(1)$ shows that $t_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ since we are repeatedly changing sign and dividing by 2 to get the next one.
And that as already noted shows the sequence of $t_k$ approaches $(a+2b)/3.$

Answer (score 1):

There is a systematic theory for finding closed forms of such linear recurrences with constant coefficients ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)). This order $d=2$ recurrence
$$
t_n = (1/2) t_{n-1} + (1/2) t_{n-2}
$$
has characteristic polynomial
$$
p(t) = t^2 - (1/2) t - 1/2
$$ 
with roots
$$
0 = p(r) = (r - 1/4)^2 - 1/16 - 1/2 \iff \\
r = \frac{1 \pm 3}{4} \in \{ 1, -1/2 \}
$$
which gives the general solution
$$
t_n = k_1 1^n + k_2 (-1/2)^n = k_1 + k_2 (-1/2)^n
$$
We need two values of $t_n$ to select the solution, e.g. $t_1$ and $t_2$:
$$
t_1 = k_1 + k_2 (-1/2)^1  = k_1 - (1/2) k_2 \\
t_2 = k_1 + k_2 (-1/2)^2 = k_1 + (1/4) k_2
$$
adding two times the second to the first equation gives
$$
t_1 + 2 t_2 = 3 k_1 \iff \\
k_1 = (1/3) t_1 + (2/3) t_2
$$
Subtracting the second from the first equation gives
$$
t_1 - t_2=-(3/4) k_2 \iff \\
k_2 = (4/3)(t_2 - t_1)
$$
So we find the closed form
$$
t_n = (1/3) t_1 + (2/3) t_2 + (4/3)(t_2-t_1)(-1/2)^n
$$
We can now go for the limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n =
\lim_{n\to\infty} (1/3) t_1 + (2/3) t_2 + (4/3)(t_2-t_1)(-1/2)^n
= (1/3) t_1 + (2/3) t_2
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I do not know about this method or characteristic polynomials so I prefer to stay away from it